# Should I use -ing in the following example?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, verb-forms, present-participles, infinitive-clauses

> In the camp we had to collect wood--an easy task since it was still
>   daylight when we arrived. The next part was harder: **build/building the
>   fire.**

Do I have to use the -ing version of the verb? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you are unsure, remove the adverb: how would you construct the sentence *without* using the word *harder*?

> The next task was building the fire.

A possible alternative would be to use the infinitive:

> The next task was to build the fire.

The colon acts as a replacement for "which was". The last sentence essentially reads:

> The next part was building the fire, which was harder.

The **act** is *building the fire*. The adverb *harder* is comparing the difficulty of the task with collecting wood.

The choice of writing the sentence using a colon is stylistic: the emphasis is on *how difficult* the task was, not *when* the task was performed.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible to read "...: build the fire." as being essentially an imperative.

Comment: @DRFYes it still works, but is non-standard in that it effectively changes tense to present: it is almost as though you are *now* ordering *yourself* to build the fire (as though the recount was being narrated from some "inner voice"). I believe this is essentially an informal  shortening of the infinitive, but to get a fuller explanation & more expert analysis, better ask on English language usage SE

Comment: Re "build the fire" : as though it were a  step in a series of instructions: 1. Gather the Wood 2. Build the Fire, where the "name" of the step (its default label) serves as the needed nominal.

Answer (score 1):

> The next part was harder: build/building the fire

Let's move the pieces around.

The next part, ______________, was harder.

The value that goes into the placeholder slot must be apposite "the next part", that is, it must be something that can function as a nominal.

One candidate is "building" since -ing forms can act as quasi-nouns.

Another candidate is a to-infinitive phrase, which also serve a nominal role.

To err is human.

To build a fire at night in driving rain is no easy task.

Comment: @martin: Agreed, the infinitive-phrase is not an imperative.  An actual imperative couldn't fill the slot, but an imperative perceived nominally could.  "The lawn mowed, I proceeded to the next task on my to-do list:  tidy your room".